# I am trying to write a function that takes n numbers of integer parameters and return the products of all the arguments

Tags: javascript, function

Here is my implementation

```
function multiplyAll(a, b, c){
    return a*b*c
}
```

This is working, but imagine we have 10 arguments, or in a case whereby we don't even know the number of arguments that will be supplied? this is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired result.

**1)**

```js
function multiplyAll(...args) {
  return args.reduce((acc, curr) => acc * curr, 1);
}

console.log(multiplyAll(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10));
```

**2)**

```js
const multiplyAll = (...args) => args.reduce((acc, curr) => acc * curr, 1);

console.log(multiplyAll(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and "clean" way to do it is by **using an array as parameter of the function**. Like so :

```js
function foo(args) {
  let res = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    res = res * args[i];
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(foo([2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arguments` like:

```js
function argumentsFunction(a,b,c,d){
  console.log(arguments); // Object of arguments
}
argumentsFunction(1,2,3,4)
```

Reference:

- [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments?retiredLocale=en)

Comment: Yes, could have been easy with array data structure. However, each argument is to be supplied as an integer and no other data structure

Comment: It's just another way.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can now use the spread operator in function parameters. You can use the following code to achieve your goal

```
function add(...numbers) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const number of numbers) { 
    total += number;
   }
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `arguments` keyword and the `Array.reduce` function from standard library.

```js
function multiplyAll(){
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((a,b) => a * b);
}
```